# T-SQL Help Needed in Converting an Appointment List into a Master Schedule

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, dynamic, schedule

I'm a self-taught SQL amateur. I don't do this for a living, but I enjoy the challenge of teaching myself. However, I've hit a wall.

In this scenario, I essentially have a three column table of appointment date/times, the length of the appointment (numeric in minutes), and the associated name of the individual handling the appointment.

What I would like to create is a weekly master schedule consisting of appointment date/times (sorted ascending) in my left most columns, the names of each respective staff member handling an appointment that week as the column names, and the the appointment length in the corresponding cell (i.e., at the intersection of the correct appointment date/time and staff name).

Now my problem is that I want to make this as flexible as possible. Staff come and go, there may or may not be appointments on any give date or time, etc. Therefore hard coding columns just isn't a good solution for me. So I'm thinking I'll need some sort of dynamic SQL and that is when I reach the end of my expertise.

I can generate a single column table of all scheduled appointment/date times across all staff (this should be sufficient to generate my left most column) for the particular week I am looking at, but from there, I'm clueless how to join in the staff/duration portion (i.e., how do I take a staff name that is in a field and turn it into a column header, how do I list only the staff who have scheduled appointments, etc.)

I was thinking about the possibility of dynamically generating temp tables for each staff's respective appointments and then dynamically joining them, but I'm not sure if that is even possible.

I know that I'm essentially creating a pivot table and I could easily copy my original dataset into Excel and create what I want manually, but I want this code to be able to be used by anyone else after I'm gone so I'd like it to be able to do all the bells and whistles internally without going to an external piece of software.

Any suggested guidance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is indeed a Dynamic Pivot. If the Appointments table looks like the following

```
CREATE TABLE Appointments
(
   ApptDatetime DATETIME,
   Staffname VARCHAR (50),
   ApptLength INT
)
```

Then the following will work:

```
DECLARE @ColumnList VARCHAR (MAX)
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)

-- Create a list of distinct Staffnames which will become column headers
SELECT @ColumnList = COALESCE(@ColumnList + '], [','[') + CAST(S.Staffname AS VARCHAR(12)) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Staffname FROM Appointments) S
SET @ColumnList = @ColumnList + ']'

SET @SQL = '
SELECT
  [ApptDatetime], ' + @ColumnList + '
FROM
(  
  SELECT
    A.[ApptDatetime],
    A.Staffname,
    A.ApptLength
  FROM
      Appointments A
  WHERE
    A.[ApptDateTime] BETWEEN GETDATE() AND DATEADD(DAY, 7, GETDATE())   
)  T
PIVOT
(
    MIN(ApptLength)
    FOR T.Staffname IN (' + @ColumnList + ')
) AS PVT'
--PRINT @SQL
exec (@SQL)
```